# CSS gradient on two-parted image

Tags: css, gradient

I have to accomplish following image by using CSS:

[image]

It's one image which will contain the main-navigation. So I wrote some CSS in order to do so (not the correct color-codes, I know):

```
#menu-block {
  background: #730868;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#730868), to(#0a9f9d));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #730868 0%, #0e70a2 76%,#0a9f9d 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #730868 0%, #0e70a2 76%,#0a9f9d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #730868 0%, #0e70a2 76%,#0a9f9d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #730868 0%, #0e70a2 76%,#0a9f9d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #730868 0%, #0e70a2 76%,#0a9f9d 100%);
  -pie-background: linear-gradient(top, #730868 0%, #0e70a2 76%,#0a9f9d 100%);
  behavior: url(/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

And this code works great! It does what it has to do except for the arrow on the end... I honestly have no idea on how to tacle this issue.
Should I create a second div in the shape of an arrow and guess the closest color?

It should support IE8...

Comment: Is the height of your menu fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This gets you close

It actually ends up with a solid colored "point" (equal to the end color of the gradient). It might be possible to actually get a continuation of the gradient into the triangle if it absolutely needs to (I don't have time at present to figure that out).

[Here's the example](http://jsfiddle.net/dLRun/8/) (note: the example uses code generated from [colorzilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for IE9 support). You need to have a fixed `width` for this to work (to set the left/right border of the psuedo-element), but the `height` can be flexible. In my example, IE8 loses the red center. Perhaps with your PIE solution, it does not.

**HTML (with IE9 condition as the example has)**

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
  <style type="text/css">
    #menu-block {
       filter: none;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->

<div id="menu-block" ></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu-block {
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;  
    background: rgb(0,0,255);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(255,255,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,255,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(255,0,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(255,255,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#0000ff', endColorstr='#ffff00',GradientType=0 );
}

#menu-block:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    border-right: 50px transparent solid;
    border-left: 50px transparent solid;
    border-bottom: 0 transparent solid;
    border-top: 30px #ffff00 solid; 
}
```

Comment: IE 10 does not support conditional comments or filters.

Comment: @Ana: IE10 should be picking up the `-ms-linear-gradient`.

Comment: @Ana: Or are you referring to the `gte IE9` in the conditional? That is the auto generated code from colorzilla. Perhaps they do that just in case IE10 (or later) decides to allow conditionals.

Comment: What Colorzilla generates isn't completely correct in January 2013. I'd wish they'd update the generator because it's a wonderful tool otherwise. Yes, I was referring to the `gte IE9`. It's not in there as future proof, it's just outdated. Just like the `-ms-linear-gradient` which I hadn't even noticed. That's not needed and it hasn't been needed for a few months. Yes, early previews for IE10 needed it. The final IE10 doesn't. Neither does the last preview for Windows 7. Both support the standard syntax. And IE9 doesn't support gradients all.

Comment: Also, the comments that Colorzilla generates with the code (if the user ticks the comments box, which I see you haven't) make it look like no browser currently supports the standard syntax. Which is not the case. For desktop, WebKit browsers are the only ones that don't support it yet (and even that is going to change). Next Opera Mobile version is going to support gradients unprefixed as well.

Comment: @Michiel Yes, it is perfectly supported by IE8, with only a gradient from blue to yellow (the red part missing). But I think that's better than using PIE.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create the full rectangle and then position and overlay triangle images at the bottom that blend with your background to give the look of a down-pointing arrow?

Comment: Ok, sounds promising! Can I do so while still supporting IE8?

Comment: I don't see why not.  I haven't tested it but it would be basic CSS2 for that part which is widely supported.